# Altium Designer, Solder mask layer

Tags: pcb, altium, pcb-layers, eda, solder-mask

I designed my first PCB and had it manufactured, but there was **no solder mask** on the manufactured PCB. Is there a specific setting that i need make in order to enable the solder mask layer? I am using **Altium Designe**r.

Thanks

Comment: Well, you need to generate the appropriate gerber, give it appropriate name, and tell the manufacturer that you want a solder mask. I.E. having it set correctly in altium i necessary but not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, Altium has a soldermask layer by default. In order to have your manufacturer include it, however, you must include xxx.GBS (bottom soldermask) and xxx.GTS (top soldermask) gerber files when you send it to them. Otherwise how will they know where the soldermask goes? In the outjob, when you set which gerbers to export, you need to make sure these layers are selected. Also, on your manufacturer's order form, make sure you specify (if required) that they have soldermask.

Who manufactured your boards?

Comment: Some local manufacturer in India. I will confirm my situation with my manufacturer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Altium designer designed PCB files by default, HAVE solder mask.

The company that has printed your PCB must have not printed the solder mask layer. maybe you had to tell them.